# Retrieving data from wp_users table in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I am new to WordPress and wish to know which is the WordPress table field that differentiate database users such as Administrator,Editor,Subscriber. I am creating admin panel like WordPress in codeigniter, so I have to fetch data from wp_users tables and want to show users roles.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should search for option name wp_user_roles in the wp_options table.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I searched for option_name wp_user_roles in the wp_options table. There is a value in option_value field like a:5:{s:13:"administrator";a:2:{s:4:"name";s:13:"Ad.........  . But I am not able to understand that. Can you explain it?

Comment: You need to unserialize this data using this function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Comment: Can you tell me what would be expected output from using unserialize() function?